# Can't use Filter realtime tweets: Twitter::Error::Unauthorized occurs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I'm working on the rails app that get a tweet including a keyword users set up. REST API is that I try to get it initially, but this API would not work for **full text match** unfortunately. If this app would work on full text match I must use `Twitter Streaming API`. So I built it like below:

```
@client = Twitter::Streaming::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
  config.consumer_secret     = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
  config.access_token        = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
  config.access_token_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
end

keywords = []
keywords.push("keyword")
options  = {
  :track    => keywords
}
tweets = @client.filter(options)
```

But `Twitter::Error::Unauthorized:` error occurs.

Comment: Check your system time. Better to do a forced NTP time sync and try the same request. If your time is too far ahead or behind UTC the token won't be valid.

Comment: That would work on Standard(free plan). https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/overview